# how to get a date from the database?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I get the date from the database
view.py:

```
entry = Comment.objects.create(
        user_id=user_id, 
        comment=comment,
        video_id=video_id,
    )   
date = str(entry.date)

print(date)
```

the result is output to the console:

```
09/11/2014 20: 31: 17.988723
```

but I need to:

```
09/11/2014 20:31:17
```

or:

```
2014-11-09 20:31:17
```

Comment: You should use some more effective debugging tools other than print. Try using pdb. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html. Inside the debugging shell you can type `dir(date)` to get all the attributes listed under date

Comment: What is your model like? Is ``Comment Date`` a datetime field? If so then its a date, just format however you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on document [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

> Return a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string.

You can use:

```
entry.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Or

```
entry.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Also you can find complete list of formating [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).